# "Data tag parsing failed: Unbalanced curly brackets"

Tags: minecraft, minecraft-commands

I've recently been trying to make a one command and have stumbled into this problem:

```
[15:13:07] Data tag parsing failed: Unbalanced curly brackets {}: {Time:1,Block:repeating_command_block,Data:1,TileEntityData:{Command:/execute @e[type=Item,score_ItemType_min=1,score_ItemType=1] ~ ~ ~ /execute @e[r=1,type=Item,score_ItemType_min=2] ~ ~ ~ /scoreboard players set @e[type=Item,r=0] ItemCreate 1 },Passengers:[{id:FallingSand,Time:1,Block:chain_command_block,Data:1,TileEntityData:{Command:execute @e[type=Item,score_ItemCreate_min=1] ~ ~ ~ /summon Item ~ ~ ~ {Motion:[0.0,1.0,0.0],Item:{id:clock,Count:1,tag:{HideFlags:63,Unbreakable:1,display:{Name:"Time_Machine",Lore:[Change Time By Simply Dropping This Item]},ench:[{id:51,lvl:0}]}}}}{id:FallingSand,Time:1,Block:chain_command_block,Data:2,TileEntityData:{Command:execute @e[type=Item,score_ItemCreate_min=1] ~ ~ ~ /summon FireworksRocketEntity ~ ~ ~ {LifeTime:0,FireworksItem:{id:fireworks,Count:1,tag:{Fireworks:{Explosions:[{Type:0,Flicker:0,Trail:1,Colors:[11743532,4312372,14602026],FadeColors:[1973019,4408131]}}}}} }}]}}
```

My command is below and I have no idea how to fix the brackets after many times of checking.

```
/summon FallingSand ~1 ~1 ~ {Time:1,Block:repeating_command_block,Data:1,TileEntityData:
{Command:/execute @e[type=Item,score_ItemType_min=1,score_ItemType=1] ~ ~ ~ /execute @e[r=1,type=Item,score_ItemType_min=2] ~ ~ ~ /scoreboard players set @e[type=Item,r=0] ItemCreate 1 },Passengers:[
{id:FallingSand,Time:1,Block:chain_command_block,Data:1,TileEntityData:
{Command:execute @e[type=Item,score_ItemCreate_min=1] ~ ~ ~ /summon Item ~ ~ ~ {Motion:[0.0,1.0,0.0],Item:{id:clock,Count:1,tag:{HideFlags:63,Unbreakable:1,display:{Name:"Time_Machine",Lore:[Change Time By Simply Dropping This Item]},ench:[{id:51,lvl:0}]}}}}
{id:FallingSand,Time:1,Block:chain_command_block,Data:2,TileEntityData:
{Command:execute @e[type=Item,score_ItemCreate_min=1] ~ ~ ~ /summon FireworksRocketEntity ~ ~ ~ {LifeTime:0,FireworksItem:{id:fireworks,Count:1,tag:{Fireworks:{Explosions:[{Type:0,Flicker:0,Trail:1,Colors:[11743532,4312372,14602026],FadeColors:[1973019,4408131]}}}}} }}]}}
```

Comment: Are you sure you have the same number opening backets "{" and closing ones "}"?

Comment: Ive Tried To Count Them And I Think I Do Just Still Obviously I Don't, I Just Cant Find The Mistake!

Comment: You have 12 times a `[` but contains the `]` only 11 times, also all of your `Command:` tags do not contain quotes like so `Command:"/some command"` and there's a comma missing before the second `{id:FallingSand`

Comment: Well In My Experience You Do Not Require To Have Quotes. I Have Looked At Many Commands That Do Not Have Them.

Comment: In My Testing This Command Works /summon FallingSand ~1 ~1 ~ {Time:1,Block:repeating_command_block,Data:1,TileEntityData:{Command:/execute @e[type=Item,score_ItemType_min=1,score_ItemType=1] ~ ~ ~ /execute @e[r=1,type=Item,score_ItemType_min=2] ~ ~ ~ /scoreboard players set @e[type=Item,r=0] ItemCreate 1 },Passengers:[{id:FallingSand,Time:1,Block:chain_command_block,Data:1,TileEntityData:{Command:/second command }}]}

Comment: And It Doesnt Have Quoets After {Command:

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a missing comma.

In using a text editor to tab-indent the command like I would any piece of code I came across this:

```
Passengers:[
    {
        ...
    }
    {
        ...
    }
}]
```

Passengers is an array of objects, there are two (or more) objects and they haven't been comma separated.

If you make the change like so:

```
Passengers:[
    {
        ...
    },
    {
        ...
    }
}]
```

then it should work (`ctrl-f` and look for `}{` and insert a comma, repeat as necessary).